# Android ripple effect outside view for pre lollipop

Tags: android

I have a circular view and what I need is to generate ripple effect outside the view with some light shade when we click on the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at these 2 libraries:

https://github.com/skyfishjy/android-ripple-background

https://github.com/ruzhan123/RippleView

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use this [**library**](https://github.com/traex/RippleEffect) to create ripple effect in pre lollipop devices too.

```
<com.andexert.library.RippleView
  android:id="@+id/more"
  android:layout_width="?android:actionBarSize"
  android:layout_height="?android:actionBarSize"
  android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/more2"
  android:layout_margin="5dp"
  rv_centered="true">

 <!--Create your circular view between these tags here -->

</com.andexert.library.RippleView>
```

Comment: Actually what I need is ripple effect "outside" the view. In case of edit icon in the sample code you have specified, it works. But when it comes to a circular view the effect is restricted inside the view. I have tried with the attributes provided by the library

Comment: Enclose your circular view between these tags. see the updated answer.